# alert message succes in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, semantic-ui

i have some problem with this program. i want to give modal use semantic-ui but its not working. when i click button order will show modal but my problem now i click button order show new page. and cannot insert to database.

view code:

```
    <div class = "ui form grid_6 omega">
        <form target="paypal" method="post">
            <div class="field1">
            <div class="field">
                <label>Nama</label>
                <input placeholder="Nama" name="nama" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label>No. HP</label>
                <input placeholder="No. HP" name="handphone" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label>Alamat</label>
                <input placeholder="alamat" name="alamat" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label>Jumlah</label>
                 <div class="selectbox">
                    <select name="jumlah" id="">
                    <?php for ($i=1; $i <= 20; $i++): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                </select>   
                 </div>

            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="ui teal button order-button">Order now</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>

        <div class="ui small modal">
                <i class="close icon"></i>
                <div class="header">
                  Smalls Like Bakin
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                  <p>Thank you for your order</p>
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                  <div class="ui positive right labeled icon button">
                    <a class="text-white" href="<?php echo site_url('home/order');?>">Back to Home</a>
                    <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

and script

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>packaged/javascript/semantic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.order-button').click(function(){
        $('.small.modal').modal('show');
    });

</script>
```

controller code;

```
    function simpanOrder()
    {
        $this->load->model("M_order");
        $data['nama'] = $_POST['nama'];
        $data['handphone'] = $_POST['handphone'];
        $data['alamat'] = $_POST['alamat'];
        $data['jumlah'] = $_POST['jumlah'];
        $result = $this->M_order->insert($data);
    }
```

can you tell me where my code problem and how to solved it? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try it by giving your modal div an id as:

```
<div id="modaldiv" class="ui small modal">
```

and make changes in your script as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.order-button').click(function(){
    $('#modaldiv').modal('show');
});  
</script>
```

Also Make sure you have included all the required javasript files to run the modal.

Comment: its working but the modal could not working well. when i click order modal show but and then modal disappear on their own. how solve this problem?

Comment: if its working for you please accept the answer. For your modal disappearing on t=its own just check that your form submits after the modal is closed.